# Как запретить вводить определенное значение в EditText?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

Есть `EditText` в котором пользователь вводит цифры, нужно запретить вводить ноль, при чем 10, 100, 1000, ...могут вводится. Как правильно прописать `inputFilter` в этом случаи?

Comment: поставить `EditText` атрибут inputType = "number" , ввод преобразовывать в число и сравнивать с 0?

Comment: @pavlofff это да, я думала может как-то в inputFilter можно красиво прописать.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Насколько я знаю, такое можно сделать только при помощи манипуляций в Java. Например, так:

```
    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if("0".equals(editText.getText())) {
                editText.setText("");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: И, что будет если набрать 12340? :)

Comment: @mit я засомневался, поэтому изменил ответ. Так точно будет правильно

Comment: Для сравнения в `equals()` разве не нужно привести к `String` - `editText.getText().toString()`?

Comment: @pavlofff, я не уверен, может и надо

Answer (score 3):

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
        {
            if (s.toString().matches("^0") ) {
                      editText.setText("");
                      editText.setError("Zero is not valid input");
            }

        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) { }
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
    });
```

Проверяем ввод регулярным выражением - если 0 в начале, то сбрасываем ввод и выводим предупреждение о ошибке ввода, чтобы пользователь не поломал экран :)

За этот код более гибкая адаптация, если требуется более сложная валидация (регулярное выражение может быть очень сложным)